# Cannot access Drive SDK API configuration with the new Google Developers Console

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-cloud-console

We have configured Google Drive API access for our Chrome packaged application to register a custom file type. Everything worked fine for more than one year.

Recently we have noticed that Drive UI does not show our custom file type icons. We try to access Drive SDK API settings for our application in the new Google Developers Console, however this option is not visible even Drive API is enabled in the APIs page. After switching to the old console the application settings for icons looks fine.

How can we fix the issue with the new Google Developers Console?

Please help.

Comment: Just letting you know that custom icons on the web should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your first question, accessing the Drive SDK configuration in the new Developers console**

*Update: This should be easy to find now.* We are aware of the difficulty of finding it, expect it to be better placed soon. In the meantime, you can find it in 2 ways:

- Search: On the API Libraries page, just search for 'Drive SDK'

[image: Searching for APIs]

- Existing users: If you enabled it previously for your project, you can find it on the 'Enabled APIs' tab in the APIs view

[image: Enabled APIs Tab]

**Your second question, custom icons in the new Drive UI**

*Update: This has been fixed on the web.* This is a change on our side, so you'll need to hang tight while we address it. There were issues with the old way we did it and we are working to address those issues.

Comment: The "Drive SDK" should now be visible in the "API Library" list just under "Drive API".

Comment: Perfect, I see the Drive SDK icon now. Thanks.